# Ler string gerada por FileReader na função result

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

Seguinte estou conseguindo pegar gerar uma string em base 64 mas não consigo pela para mandar para o meu servidor, segue o código:

```
      $scope.cadastraFoto = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('fotoPerfil').files[0]

    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(input)
    console.log(reader)
    var teste = reader.result
    console.log(teste)

  }
```

O resultado no console fica assim :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que no result existe uma string que se eu pegá-la e jogar em um conversor online minha foto sera renderizada.
Agora meu grande problema, porque não consigo atribuir esta string a uma variável ou mandar esse objeto para meu servidor ?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você não está buscando a string da forma correta.

Já tive que fazer exatamente o mesmo trabalho há um tempo atrás, porém, fiz em jquery:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
var anexo = $("#seuInput").get(0).files[0];
var nomeAnexo = anexo.name;
var dataUrl = "";

fileReader.filename = nomeAnexo;
fileReader.onloadend = function(result) {

    //Atribui string em base 64 à variável
    dataUrl = fileReader.result.split(';base64,')[1];

    //-- Chame aqui sua função para enviar os dados para o servidor

};
fileReader.readAsDataURL(anexo);
```

Espero que te ajude. Boa sorte!